# Intellij breakpoint not stopping

Tags: java, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I have not worked with Intellij or Java before, and tried setting a breakpoint like in the picture below. Is there a reason why my code would not be stopping? I've read other answers about intellij breakpoints, but they were about multithreaded applications. I just downloaded intellij too, so I know I have the newest community version.

[image]

Comment: I think break points should be on your next statement Board myboard = new Board(8); In eclipse, you can't even put a break point at that location(variable declaration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> No executable code found...

Just init your local variable and debugger suspend on it:

[image]

5 line have next code:

```
Integer count;
```

Check this **[guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Debugger)** for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set a breakpoint in a next row. Java cant stop at lines without any action. You will see check icon in breakpoint when you select a proper line.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration itself isn't really executable code - it's just declaring the existence of something. You should breakpoint on Board myboard... which actually does something.